# What is NSXMLParserErrorDomain error?

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing

I am getting this parser error while accessing the server url

Parser Error : Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=5 "Operation could not be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)"

What does this mean  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html), this error means:

> NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError
>
> ```
> The document ended unexpectedly.
>
> Available in Mac OS X v10.3 and later.
>
> Declared in NSXMLParser.h.
> ```